# Same variables in different '<script>' tags without them clashing?

Tags: javascript, variables, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I want to use same variables in different `<script>` code blocks without them clashing. My code looks roughly like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ad = document.getElementById('sidebar1-ad');

        if (ad.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
            adWidth = ad.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        } else {
            adWidth = ad.offsetWidth;
        }

        ...
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ad = document.getElementById('article-footer-ad');

        if (ad.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
            adWidth = ad.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        } else {
            adWidth = ad.offsetWidth;
        }

        ...
    </script>
</head>

<body> ... </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, variables `ad` and `adWidth` in the second code block seem to take precedence.

Is there a way I can use the same variable names in different `<script>` tags in a page without any one overwriting the other? If so, how?

Comment: You need to namespace then, or isolate them within functions and use the car keyword.

Comment: Uh... Var. Thanks, phone.

Comment: @DaveNewton Heh, I was wondering... :P Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change you script body, just wrap your code to an anonymous function and call it immediately. Also, you need to use `var` keyword to limit variable scope.

```
<script>
  (function() {

      var ad = document.getElementById('article-footer-ad');

      // your code here ...

  })(); // <-- this is an immediate call
</script>
```

Also, if code in every block is the same, consider refactoring it to a single function and use in other code blocks

```
<script>
    // Common function

    function renderAd(adId) {

        var ad = document.getElementById(adId);

    }
</script>
...
<script>
    renderAd('sidebar1-ad');
</script>
...
<script>
    renderAd('article-footer-ad');
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I "call it"?

Comment: Yep, just noticed it. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function()
{
    var ad = document.getElementById('sidebar1-ad');

    if (ad.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
        var adWidth = ad.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    } else {
        var adWidth = ad.offsetWidth;
    }

    ...
})();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function()
{
    var ad = document.getElementById('article-footer-ad');

    if (ad.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
        var adWidth = ad.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    } else {
        var adWidth = ad.offsetWidth;
    }

    ...
})();
</script>
```

...

Comment: By the way, isn't `var` required for the `adWidth` variable too?